# Methods to insert or replace values in to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an object like this

```
var obj2= {
        'home' : {
            '1' : {
                  'year' : '1999'
                  },
            '2' : {
                  'year' : '2000'
                  'month' : '11'
                  },
        },
        'company' : {
            '1' : {
                  'year' : '2010'
                  'month' : '2'
                  },
        }
    };
```

And I would like to add some more keys inside the object or replace value if this key chain already exists, for ex:

```
buss_type = "home",
type_id = "1",
date_type = "month",
value = "9"

var tmp_obj1 = {[buss_type]: {[type_id]: {[date_type]: value}}};
```

and

```
buss_type = "company",
type_id = "2",
date_type = "month",
value = "12"

var tmp_obj2 = {[buss_type]: {[type_id]: {[date_type]: value}}};
```

to make object:

```
obj = {
    'home' : {
        '1' : {
            'year' : '1999',
            'month' : '9'
        },
        '2' : {
            'year' : '2000',
            'month' : '11'
        },
    },
    'company' : {
        '1' : {
            'year' : '2020',
            'month' : '10'
        },
        '2' : {
            'month' : '12'
        }
    },
};
```

Arrays methods like `.push()` or `.concat()` adding new keys on the end only instead of replacing values of existing ones.

Are there any object methods that can make it easy to manage or should I just use loops and check all keys before adding new or changing value of existing one?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an array, so why the reference on `.push()` and `.concat()`?

Comment: [Braket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) will help you in accessing property inside object

Comment: I suggest  making home and company arrays `[{year:"1999",month:"9"}, {year:"2000",month:"11"}]` and so on. Then you can do something like: `obj.home.push(newObject)` and `obj.home[0].month = 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array for the keys and save the last key for direct assignment.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();
    path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = { home: { 1: { year: '1999' }, 2: { year: '2000', month: '11' } }, company: { 1: { year: '2010', month: '2' } } };

setValue(object, ["home", "1", "month"], "9");
setValue(object, ["company", "2", "month"], "12");

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This may be very old, but how would you use this setValue and update it to create a new key: value pair if the specified key doesn't exist?

Comment: @Jay, do you have an example?

Comment: So in your example, if a year key doesn't exist in the original object, can we create a year key and add our defined value to the desired child object? I'm just starting to push into more advanced JS (this is to me!) and I'd love to understand how I could add this myself.

Comment: `reduce` here add a new key with object for every unknown key until the last one there, it assigns the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` method to add nested properties to object.

```js
var obj2 = {"home":{"1":{"year":"1999"},"2":{"year":"2000","month":"11"}},"company":{"1":{"year":"2010","month":"2"}}}

function add(obj, value, ...keys) {
  keys.reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    return r[e] || (r[e] = arr[i + 1] ? {} : value)
  }, obj)
}

let buss_type = "home", type_id = "1", date_type = "month", value = "9";
add(obj2, value, buss_type, type_id, date_type)

buss_type = "company", type_id = "2", date_type = "month", value = "12"
add(obj2, value, buss_type, type_id, date_type)

console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: This seems convoluted; defining each key/value individually and putting them into a function, and why are numbers strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you will only have objects without any methods inside, just simple JSON style objects. Then you can use something like

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Just be careful that the order of the object data is important. For example, this will return false

```
 x = {a: 1, b: 2};
 y = {b: 2, a: 1};
```

Comment: If I will try add:

`var obj3 = {
        'home' : {
            '1' : {
                  'year' : '1999'
                  }
        },
    };`

to the:

`var obj2 = {
        'home' : {
            '1' : {
                  'year' : '1999'
                  },
            '2' : {
                  'year' : '2000',
                  'month' : '11'
                  }
        }
    };`

`JSON.stringify(obj2) === JSON.stringify(obj3)` will always show false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a loop instead you can programmatically access the key you're about to add using this syntax:

```
buss_type = "home",
type_id = "1",
date_type = "month",
value = "9"

if(obj[buss_type]){
   if(obj[buss_type][type_id]){
      obj[buss_type][type_id][date_type] =  value
   }else{
       obj[buss_type][type_id] = { date_type: value }
   }
}else{
    obj[buss_type] = { type_id: { date_type: value } }
}
```